# How could I remove 3D axes and print in eps?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

So far I got this code, and I would like the 3D plot but without the axes and printed in eps vectorial format.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# coding: latin-1
import os, sys

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig, azim = -128, elev = 43)

s = .05
X = np.arange(-2, 2.+s, s)
Y = np.arange(-1, 3.+s, s)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = (1.-X)**2 + 100.*(Y-X*X)**2
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride = 1, cstride = 1, norm = LogNorm(), cmap = cm.jet,linewidth=0)

plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")

plt.savefig("Rosenbrock function.svg")

plt.show()
```

Comment: for eps, you should be able to just write 'plt.savefig("Rosenbrock function.eps")', but that depends if your backend supports eps (most do according to the savefig documentation)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. But when the save window poped-up I changed the extension and that did the trick, but perhaps there's a better an formal way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: What if you try explicitly specifying the format:  'plt.savefig("Rosenbrock function.eps", format='eps')'?

Comment: It didn't work :c , by the way I'm running it on TextWrangler on a Mac.

Comment: What backend are you using? import matplotlib as mpl; mpl.get_backend()

Comment: I'm reading about backend, don't know what it is for

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930524/how-to-set-backend-in-matplotlib-in-python

Comment: but I don't have any problem with the printing, I get the image, I just would like to save it on eps without the axes.

Comment: What happens when you do `plt.savefig('rosenbrock.eps')`? Does it produce a file? If so, can you open the file as an EPS? If not, is there an error of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question about turning off the axes is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336927/how-can-i-hide-the-axes-in-matplotlib-3d). To summarize, you want to add the line

```
ax.set_axis_off()
```

if you have a newer version of Matplotlib. If that doesn't work, you can try

```
ax._axis3don = False
```

or just upgrade your Matplotlib.

Comment: found it!
  fig.patch.set_visible(False)
  ax.axis('off')