# Remove whitespace of 3D plot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I've googling around for days now to solve a presumably easy problem:
I want to generate a 3D plot with matplotlib. This works nicely, and I can rotate the plot in the right position.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,6), facecolor="white")

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (0,0), colspan=2, rowspan=2, projection="3d")



def cc(SpectrumType):
    if SpectrumType == "Normal":
        return "tab:gray"
    if SpectrumType == "Anomaly":
        return mcolors.to_rgba("r", alpha=1)   


# X Axis : equally space from 0 to 10
xs = np.arange(0, 20, 0.4)

verts = []

# 3 D axis: draw 4 plots at points 0, 1, 2, 3
zs = [0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 12.0, 14.0, 16.0, 18.0]

afactor = 1
for z in zs:
    afactor = 1
    if z==10.0:
        afactor = 5
    ys = afactor*np.random.rand(len(xs))
    ys[0], ys[-1] = 0, 0
    verts.append(list(zip(xs, ys)))



poly = PolyCollection(verts)
poly.set_alpha(0.5)

ax1.add_collection3d(poly, zs=zs, zdir='x')

ax1.set_xlabel('X')
ax1.set_xlim3d(-1, 21)
ax1.set_ylabel('Y')
ax1.set_ylim3d(0, 20)
ax1.set_zlabel('Z')
ax1.set_zlim3d(0, 5)
ax1.set_title("Plot 1")

ax1.view_init(8,-82) 
ax1.get_proj = lambda: np.dot(Axes3D.get_proj(ax1), np.diag([0.3, 1, 0.3, 
0.3]))


plt.tight_layout(pad=0)#, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=5.0)
fig.subplots_adjust(top=1, bottom=0, left=0, right=1)
fig = plt.gcf()
plt.legend(loc='upper right')#, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

Generated 3D plot:

[image]

PROBLEM: There is always white space on the left side of the plot. This drives me crazy! I want to add this 3D as a subplot to a grid, but this white space makes the entire figure look really ugly. Please help ! How do I remove this white space on the left?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Set a negative number for `left` - `fig.subplots_adjust(top=1, bottom=0, left=-0.1, right=1)`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't change a thing for me. I've tried it before. Did you try it on your own? Maybe there's something wrong with other settings on my machine? I've seen what you labelled "possible duplicate" and really this looks similar but doesn't help me :(

Comment: Yep it works on my machine. What version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: my version is 2.0.2

Comment: I updated via conda now, there is now change :(

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225293/remove-white-spaces-in-axes3d-matplotlib