# How to disable border in subplot for a 3D plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following code which produces two plots in matplotlib.

However, each I'm unable to remove this border in the second subplot despite feeding all these arguments.

How can I remove the black border around the second subplot (see attached image)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

beta, gamma = np.linspace(-np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, 500), np.linspace(-np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, 500)
B, G = np.meshgrid(beta, gamma)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))

# 2D Contour plot
ax1.imshow(obj_vals.T, origin='lower', cmap='hot', extent=(-np.pi/2, np.pi/2, -np.pi/2, np.pi/2))
ax1.set_xlabel(r'$\gamma$')
ax1.set_ylabel(r'$\beta$')
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_yticks([])


ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
# Make panes transparent
ax2.xaxis.pane.fill = False # Left pane
ax2.yaxis.pane.fill = False # Right pane
ax2.zaxis.pane.fill = False # Right pane

# Remove grid lines
ax2.grid(False)
# Remove tick labels
ax2.set_xticklabels([])
ax2.set_yticklabels([])
ax2.set_zticklabels([])

# Transparent spines
ax2.xaxis.line.set_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax2.yaxis.line.set_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax2.zaxis.line.set_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))

ax2.w_xaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax2.w_yaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))

# No ticks
ax2.set_xticks([]) 
ax2.set_yticks([]) 
ax2.set_zticks([])

# Surface plot
surf = ax2.plot_surface(B, G, obj_vals.T, cmap='hot')


plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you are creating a subplot with two 2D axes and then adding a 3D axis over the right 2D one. You have removed the splines for the 3D plot, but the original 2D plot that you originally made is still there. I think a better way to do this would be to create the figure and then the subplots individually, like what is shown on [this documentation page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/mixed_subplots.html).

Then, you can also remove all the 3D axes components using `ax.set_axis_off()`, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64843559/12131013).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.close("all")

x = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.sin(X)*np.cos(Y)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax1.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=100, cmap="hot")
ax1.set_xlabel(r'$\gamma$')
ax1.set_ylabel(r'$\beta$')
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_yticks([])


ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection="3d")
ax2.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap="hot", rstride=1, cstride=1)
ax2.set_axis_off()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]